# Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.dll'

Tags: c#, expression, encoder

i just wrote a program that uses microsoft encoders and merge videos and audios , its working fine in my PC (Windows7 ) and when i test it on other PCs (Windows7,Windows XP [.net 4.0 installed]] it is giving me following exception

its even giving me exception when i try to run the sample sdk applications to other pcs ..(with no microsoft expression installed)

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass

embly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.dll' or one of its dependencies. T

he specified module could not be found.

at Simple.Program.Main(String[] args)

how can i solve this error ,

or what are the ways to deploy standalone application , without pc pre installed microsoft expression studio.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.dll` is part of Expression Studio. If it isn't installed on the target machine it will not be found.

I don't know if these DLLs can be freely distributed, but you should find out before trying to distribute them with your application.

Comment: This is it.  Don't copy, just install it.

Comment: Expression Studio can be found here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870

Answer (score 0):

try to locate this dll-file on your machine, and distribute it with your executable to a pc that hasn't got expression installed.

when a program is about to use a dll, it looks in some predesignated places on the computer. one of the first places is in the folder the executable is executed in. one of the later places is probably c:\windows\system32

you have the filename though, so it shouldn't be that hard. unless microsoft has created some sort of mechanism stopping the distribution of the expression utilities.